# How to add a callback for setAttribute?

Tags: javascript, callback, prototype

Is it possible to add a callback on `setAttribute` on Prototype ?

For this example, I would like to show an `alert("done !")` when `setAttribute()` is finished.

```
img.setAttribute("src", "http://blabla.com/c.jpg");
```

Comment: Why? `setAttribute` isn't asynchronous.

Comment: Re update: Given your example, are you asking how to run a function when the image has finished loading? Because that will happen some time after the attribute has finished being set.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you mean Prototype as the JavaScript library or prototype as the `prototype` property on JavaScript objects?

Comment: Prototype as the JavaScript library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
(function() {

    var elementSetAttribute = Element.prototype.setAttribute;

    Element.prototype.setAttribute = function() {
        whateverFunctionYouWant.call(this);

        return elementSetAttribute.apply(this, arguments);
    }

})();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWVWn/).

This will call `whateverFunctionYouWant()` when you do something such as `document.links[0].setAttribute('href', '/')`.

You seem to want this to call a callback when you change the `src` attribute of `img` elements and the new resource has loaded...

```
(function() {

    var HTMLImageElementSetAttribute = HTMLImageElement.prototype.setAttribute;

    HTMLImageElement.prototype.setAttribute = function(attribute, value) {
        var image;

        if (attribute == 'src') {
            image = new Image;
            image.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
            image.src = value;
        }

        return HTMLImageElementSetAttribute.apply(this, arguments);
    }

})();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgcSQ/).

You could overload `setAttribute()` here with a third parameter, which would be the callback.

In my opinion and experience, I'd create a different function instead for doing this. Modifying prototypes is one thing, but overloading native DOM methods to do extra things sounds like inviting trouble, especially once a developer unfamiliar with what you've done looks at the code.

It goes without saying that if you want the latter example to work < IE9, use the `attachEvent()` fallback for adding the event listener.

Comment: @Steffi Do you mean you want a callback when you change an `img` element's `src` attribute and the new resource has downloaded?

Comment: I have nothing more to say. You're amazing.

Comment: I found a problem with your function : if the image is already loaded once, the callback is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

May be not the golden solution but

```
img.setAttribute("src", "http://blabla.com/c.jpg");
img.onload = imageCallback;

function imageCallback() { ... }
```

If you are interested in jQuery, there is plugin called **[waitforimages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages)** that might help.

Comment: Polling isn't the best solution, when the `load` event is available.

Comment: What's happen if `img` is already load ? I need to do the callback every time I setAttribute.

Comment: @Steffi, But didn't you wanted a callback when you `setattribute`

Comment: Yes. setAttribute Then Callback of setAttribute.

Comment: @Steffi, Either way, the callback will be called once the image has been loaded on to the element.

Comment: Nope, if the image is already loaded once, the callback is not executed.

Comment: @Steffi, Try out the plugin I linked above